# MATLAB: 3 vectors contour plotting

Tags: matlab, contour

Can you help me with this contour plotting? i have a .dat archive, there i have 4 columns with 55 values each.

```
X,n,log10(resistivity),Y
-3.50, -1.00, 0.99, -1.00
-2.50, -1.00, 0.98, -1.00 
-1.50, -1.00, 0.90, -1.00 
-0.50, -1.00, 1.26, -1.00 
0.50, -1.00, 1.26, -1.00 
1.50, -1.00, 1.26, -1.00 
2.50, -1.00, 2.02, -1.00 
3.50, -1.00, 2.01, -1.00 
-4.00, -2.00, 0.98, -1.50 
-3.00, -2.00, 0.96, -1.50 
-2.00, -2.00, 0.83, -1.50 
-1.00, -2.00, 1.26, -1.50 
0.00, -2.00, 1.26, -1.50 
1.00, -2.00, 1.26, -1.50 
2.00, -2.00, 1.26, -1.50 
3.00, -2.00, 2.04, -1.50 
4.00, -2.00, 2.02, -1.50
```

and so on until 55 values... i know that the n=1 repeats 8 times, n=2 repeats 9, n=repeats 10 times, n=4 repeats 9 times, n=5 repeats 10 times and n=6 repeats 9 times.

I have to make a contour `X,N,log10(resistivity)`.
i just dont know how to contour it.

i read like this:

```
datos3=dlmread('salida.dat',',',1)
XX=datos3(:,1)
NN=datos3(:,2)
RHOA=datos3(:,3)
YY=datos3(:,4)
```

could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
x = datos3(:,1);
y = datos3(:,2);
z = datos3(:,3);

xmesh = linspace(min(x),max(x));
ymesh = linspace(min(y),max(y));
[Xi,Yi] = meshgrid(xmesh, ymesh);

F = TriScatteredInterp([x,y], z);
Zi = F(Xi,Yi);

contour(Xi,Yi,Zi)
```

I hope this helps.